# standardize function in glmnet in R

Tags: r, regression, glmnet

```
set.seed(123)
n = 100
p = 20
x =  matrix(rnorm(n * p, mean = 2, sd = 2), n, p)
y =  rnorm(n)
lambda = 0.05

fit1 =  glmnet(x,y, lambda = lambda)
beta1 = as.vector(coef(fit1, s = lambda, exact = TRUE))
beta1[which(abs(beta1) > 0)]

xsd = apply(x, 2, function(x) (x  - mean(x))/sqrt(var(x) * (n - 1) / n))
fit2 =  glmnet(xsd,y,lambda = lambda, standardize = FALSE)
beta2 = as.vector(coef(fit2, s = lambda, exact = TRUE))
beta2[which(abs(beta2) > 0)]

est.table = data.frame("beta1" = beta1[which(abs(beta1) > 0)], "beta2" = beta2[which(abs(beta2) > 0)])
```

I want assume the outputs should be same for both Lasso problem solved by glmnet. One with original data(standardize = TRUE) and other with standardized data(standardize = FALSE). But why the outputs are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

When you have `standardize = TRUE`, the coefficients are returned in the original scale. This means you can use this together with your input matrix to get the predictions.

If you look at the input for your non standardized glmnet, the input is divided by the standard deviation, meaning your coefficients will be scaled up the standard deviation.

To compare them with a regression with standardized input, you need to divide the coefficient from the non-standardized glmnet by the standard deviation of each column:

```
set.seed(123)
n = 100
p = 20
x =  matrix(rnorm(n * p, mean = 2, sd = 2), n, p)
y =  rnorm(n)
lambda = c(0.01,0.05,0.1,0.5,1)

fit1 =  glmnet(x,y, lambda = lambda,standardize = TRUE)
beta1 = as.matrix(fit1$beta)

xsd = apply(x, 2, function(x) (x  - mean(x))/sqrt(var(x) * (n - 1) / n))
fit2 =  glmnet(xsd,y,lambda = lambda, standardize = FALSE)
beta2 = as.matrix(fit2$beta)
```

Now we get the sd for each column:

```
colsd = apply(x, 2, function(x)sqrt(var(x) * (n - 1) / n))
```

And we divide the coefficients from the standardized by this sd:

```
head(sweep(beta2,1,colsd,"/"))
   s0 s1         s2           s3           s4
V1  0  0 0.00000000 -0.014049634 -0.032142780
V2  0  0 0.00000000 -0.001181405 -0.026486241
V3  0  0 0.01605406  0.051932402  0.082018905
V4  0  0 0.00000000  0.000000000  0.000000000
V5  0  0 0.00000000  0.000000000  0.004122524
V6  0  0 0.00000000  0.000000000  0.000000000
```

And compare with the other regression:

```
head(beta1)
   s0 s1         s2           s3           s4
V1  0  0 0.00000000 -0.014049634 -0.032142780
V2  0  0 0.00000000 -0.001181405 -0.026486241
V3  0  0 0.01605406  0.051932402  0.082018905
V4  0  0 0.00000000  0.000000000  0.000000000
V5  0  0 0.00000000  0.000000000  0.004122524
V6  0  0 0.00000000  0.000000000  0.000000000
```

Comment: It makes sense! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @StupidWolf ! I have one question to double-check if I understand correctly. So... if I manually scale the data (e.g., using a scale() function producing mean 0 and var 1), then should I use "standardize = FALSE" in the glmnet function? If I scale the data in advance & use "standardize = TRUE", then it is over-standardizing, right?